# git push -u origin main is not working and showing any message. it also not asking for credentials. What is the reason and what is the solution?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, github

git push -u origin main is  not working and showing any message. it also not asking for credentials. What is the reason and what is the solution ?

Comment: Set `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/reponame` before executing `git push origin`

Comment: It's not working.